# Returning ServiceFault & Response using a single @Async method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, future

I am using @Async annotation and Java Future to call a webservice asynchronously by passing different employee ids.

```
@Async
public Future<Employee> getEmployeeDetails(String id){

    // Call external service
    return new AsyncResult<Employee>(response);
}
```

My calling code is similar to below

```
Future<Employee> employeeFuture = asyncCustomerImpl.getEmployeeDetails("1415");
employeeList.add(employeeFuture.get());
```

I am able to get the response however I want to handle some of unchecked exceptions returned and return back a customer friendly message. However using this code , I am unable to catch the exception in the calling code. Please can you help with the logic that I need to follow.

EDIT:

Calling Method:

```
   try{
        employee = employeeFuture.get();
        System.out.println(" employee is " + employee);
    } catch (FrameworkError ex) {
        System.out.println(" Framework Error " + e);        
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(" InterruptedException" + e);    
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(" ExecutionException " + e);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(" General Exception ");
    }
```

Called (Async Method)

```
@Async
public Future<Employee> getEmployeeDetails(String id){

    try{
     // Call external service
    } catch (Exception e){
       Throw new FrameworkError(e);
    }
    return new AsyncResult<Employee>(response);
}
```

When I run the above code , I see employee is null in the result.  I am unable to see the control going to any of the catch blocks.

Error Log

> ERROR 6412 --- [task-scheduler-2] handler.LoggingHandler   : java.lang.RuntimeException
>       at service.impl.EmployeeImpl.getEmployeeDetails(AsyncEmployeeImpl.java:49)
>       at service.impl.AsyncTicketsImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$576d0436.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler$DelegatingErrorHandlingCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:386)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Created a standalone app (https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/#initial) and returned an exception and  I am able to see the exception on .get as expected. However when I ran this code within my larger program , I wasnt able to see the exception.

Stacktrace from standalone app :

> at hello.FacebookLookupService.findPage(FacebookLookupService.java:22)
>       at hello.FacebookLookupService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8016679.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Stacktrace from my app is already pasted above. This is the primary difference that I see :

> at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler$DelegatingErrorHandlingCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:386)

The working standalone app did not have this line in the log. When I looked at this class (org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler), I saw the below. It is returning null instead of exception which I guess is causing the error :

```
        @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
        try {
            return this.delegate.call();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            this.errorHandler.handleError(t);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is this exception? What throws it?

Comment: I make a call to external service (// Call external service). It returns a number of service faults. Apart from that take a case where there is a connection timeout. How can these be propagated to calling code ( customerTicketFuture.get()). I basically want to have a try / catch block around customerTicketFuture.get() and handle the exceptions that are returned by the asyc process.

Comment: If an exception is thrown in the `@Async` method, it will be intercepted by the AOP handler and re-thrown in your `Future#get` call.

Comment: In order to test , I am throwing a custom exception which extends RuntimeException. In the calling code , I have customerTicketFuture.get() within try block. However when the exception is thrown , I am not able to see the text within the catch block being printed.

Comment: Please show what you are doing, an MCVE ideally. Note that `get` wraps the thrown exception in its own (`ExecutionException` iirc).

Comment: Thanks for your time , Sotirios. I have updated additional details.

Comment: I don't know what `FrameworkError` is, so I replaced it with a simple `RuntimeException` wrapping the `e` and it works for me. `get` throws an `ExecutionException` which is caught by the corresponding `catch` block and prints it out. You can un-nest exception to get the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. I will try it out.

Comment: I tried throwing a RuntimeException as well. However no exception was returned on performing a get and the next line executed successfully. I am getting a feeling that it is being caught and handled prior to control being returned to future .get.  I have pasted the error log that I printed.Is this of any help?

Comment: I'd ask you to provide a complete and runnable example (an MCVE). I've tried something and it works, but I can't (don't want to) assume anything about your deployment or setup.

Comment: Apologies  , I was trying  to recreate it by creating a standalone app , but wasn't able to. This is part of a large program within my company , so finding it difficult to extract relevant pieces. I did further analysis and updated in the original post. Please can you help in checking and see if this provides any leads?

Comment: Yeah, if you're swallowing the exception, there's not much you can do. Maybe deal with `null` as if it was an error. Can't get the cause at that point though.

Comment: This method is provided by Spring & it is in org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler class. Is there a reason why Spring is swallowing this exception and is there any workaround that can be suggested to get the actual exception?

Comment: The documentation for call method also shows that it returns "Exception"  - http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.8.RELEASE_to_4.0.9.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.0.9.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.DelegatingErrorHandlingCallable.html. But it is looks they are returning a null instead.

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was a Spring class. You seem to be using an `ErrorHandler`. Only if you specify an `ErrorHandler` does Spring handle the exception itself and return `null`. If you don't specify one, it will bubble up the exception to the `Future`.

Comment: Thanks you! How can I check if an ErrorHandler is being used?

Comment: Check your `@Async` configuration (maybe through `@EnableAsync` or a `AsyncConfigurerSupport`). Look into which `Executor` you've provided, and how you've configured it. In this case, it seems like a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` where you're registering an `ErrorHandler` with `setErrorHandler`.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any specific executor defined along with EnableAsync. But I will check again. Is there any way to define a executor along with @Async annotation which will enable Spring to bubble up the excption to Future.

Comment: Yes, look into `AsyncConfigurerSupport`.